# Powershell : Find the first free computer name in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

I try to build a script that find the first free computer name in Active Directory

For example, if I have these computers in AD : 
 - PC01
 - PC02
 - PC04
 - PC05

I try to find PC03 but all script i found for this will return : PC06 (List > Take the last one and increment)

Does someone have any idea how I can find this ?

Best regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$computers = Get-ADComputer * | % { $_.Name -replace 'PC' }

$i = 1
while ( $computers -contains ("{0:d2}" -f $i) ) { $i++ }

$computername = "PC{0:d2}" -f $i

echo $computername
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$names = echo PC01  PC02  PC04  PC05
#$names = Get-ADComputer -Filter *  | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^PC\d+$'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
[int[]]$num = $names -replace '\D+'

for($i=0; $i -lt $num.Count; $i++) 
{  
    if($num[$i+1]-$num[$i] -gt 1) 
    {
        'PC{0:00}' -f ($num[$i]+1); break
    }         
}

PC03
```

Comment: It's work except i don't have RSAT on my computer but I used an other way you described on another topic (with adsisearcher) and that works perfectly. Thanks a lot